# Android - How to enable Bluetooth to be always on?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Two question on Bluetooth development on Android:

1. Is there a way to enable Bluetooth to be always on (I might have a long device discovery phase in my application) in Android? As far as I can see the default value is a count down from 120s.
2. Does it exist any open source Bluetooth API implementations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bluetooth implementation is now available in the Android 2.0 API. 
See [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html).

Comment: Yes, I saw the news too. Finally available :)

Comment: Bluetooth is available in the SDK but the AVD doesn't support 2.0 API (level 5) or the doc isn't up-to-date : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html

Comment: The overview link may be a better starting place than the other two links:
http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 2):

Enabling Bluetooth to be always on, may not be a good decision, if your only concern is long discovery delay ("battery life"-wise).

As for third-party Bluetooth APIs, the only thing that I've heard of is [iAnywhere Blue SDK](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1064424) (from Sybase, not free, only evaluation version available), which covers some of the features, that will be supported in the future from the *system/bluetooth* and *bluez* packages.

According to the Android's [Bluetooth roadmap](http://source.android.com/projects/bluetooth-features), most of the long waited things like Java API, Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR will be implemented, at one point in the future.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for your battery advice, but at this stage in the project I do not care about the battery, only about constant Bluetooth :)

Answer (score 2):

On 2.3.6 I can keep the device always visible by putting the delay 0:

```
Intent di = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
di.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) stack on Linux is an open source implementation. It's also available on Windows but the API is much more complete on Linux.

When you say, 'enable Bluetooth to always be on' do you mean, always trying to discover other devices?

Most bluetooth chips have a deep sleep mode, where the chip is mostly down and just comes up a to check for  activity on any established links. It will only wake up to full power when you want it to do something (discovery, make a connection) or there is activity on an existing link.

Yeah, it uses more battery power than if the Bluetooth were totally off but it's not a total vampire.

Comment: Yes, with always on I mean constant client discovery. The "problem" with android is the default 120s countdown. Is this changable? Lets say 600s?

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
        BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE

Comment: This is not always on (or discoverable as the original asker meants), this prompts user confirmation.

Comment: We can never make a device to always visible in android but we can extend its time from 120s to 300s.

Answer (score 0):

[BlueCove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) is an open-source bluetooth implementation for Java.

It works on a lot of different machines and if correct there is a Android compatible version lurking around somewhere.