# Connecting My Android app with wifi printer for printing bills

Tags: android, printing, wifi, printers, thermal-printer

I am trying to print a set of values through a wifi printer without internet.How to detect the list of wifi printers and connect to them.The tough part is how to start printing when the data is sent from mobile android app.Sample code will be very helpful.

Note : we are not supposed to use any secondary applications and also it should not depend on printers from specific manufacturer.It should detect all the printers available through wifi and print through  the selected printer.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656199/bluetooth-and-wifi-printing-for-android)

Comment: thanks for your reply but we are not supposed to use any secondary applications and also it should not depend on printers from specific manufacturer.It should detect and through print  all the printers available through wifi.