# Android-How to develop print option in web view?

Tags: android, printing, webview

I have developed a android web view where a specific url is loaded. Now I want to develop a print option to print the full web view (just as the print option of any browser app has e.g. chorme browser of android version). Can anyone has any idea to do this? Besides, is it possible to print any screen from any android application??

N.B. ** I have to print in a wifi enabled printer which has NFS technology also

** I don't want to use google cloud printing.

Comment: do u know Google Cloud printing  in andorid

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't want to use that so that it can be printed without internet connection also (just using NFS or WiFi)

Comment: this is possable on in 4.4 android device becouse this feature are add in 4.4 api level have a any 4.4 kitket device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656199/bluetooth-and-wifi-printing-for-android

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar thanks for your link (though I have seen it before), basically I don't want to be version specific, isn't it possible to do something for older version also?