# Android 4.2 - Printing using network printer

Tags: android, printing, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need a print a receipt from a receipt printer(network printer) via my android application which is developed by 4.2 version.
is Android 4.2 support printing from the network printer?
can any one please point me to a correct tutorial.
Thanks

Comment: are you fix your problem? i need solution for that help me plz

Answer (score 0):

device connected to a network will communicate via their IP and Ports / sockets.

```
    try 
   {
    Socket sock = new Socket("IP", port);
    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    oStream.println("");
    oStream.println("");
    oStream.close();
      sock.close(); 
  }
  catch (UnknownHostException e) 
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) 
 { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

how to print :

```
     private void doPrint() {
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
printManager.print("My document", new CustomPrintDocumentAdapter(getActivity()), null);
     }
```

where CustomPrintDocumentAdapter extends[PrintDocumentAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656199/bluetooth-and-wifi-printing-for-android)

and more info about prnting [Android Devlprs](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html)

more details [Refer](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/632582/Printing-in-Android-using-WIFI-printer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.cannot find PrinterManager Class.